# How to make gcc emit basic_block markers in DWARF output?

Tags: debugging, gcc, dwarf

(Probably unneeded context:)
I want to combine information obtained within a gcc plugin with the addresses of the actual basic blocks. Because the final addresses are not known within the plugin unfortunately but only after linking, I need to recover the basic blocks from the .elf file. One way to do so is by using DWARF's `basic_block` markers for instructions at the start of basic blocks stored in the `.debug_line` section. These can then be read (e.g., with the elftools Python library) and (potentially, I haven't tried yet) matched with file+line+column data available in DWARF as well as the plugin.

My problem is that I cannot get gcc or ld (or even clang) to emit the `basic_block` markers directly for the whole binary but have to generate the assembly code (e.g., `gcc -S -g3`), add `.loc_mark_labels 1` on top, and then assemble this file. Is there a better way to force the `basic_block` tags?